# System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value

Tags: android, json, rest, android-studio

I'm developping web service application and im using rest api and i want test it with json.

when i run my application i have this error:

> D/REQUEST Result: result =
>   {"result":[{"id":"1","name":"achref","mat":"achref","duration":"achref","imageRes":"http://127.0.0.1/asd.jpg"},{"id":"2","name":"achref","mat":"achref","duration":"achref","imageRes":"http://127.0.0.1/asd.jpg"},{"id":"3","name":"achref","mat":"achref","duration":"achref","imageRes":"http://127.0.0.1/asd.jpg"},{"id":"4","name":"achref","mat":"achref","duration":"achref","imageRes":"http://127.0.0.1/asd.jpg"},{"id":"5","name":"achref","mat":"achref","duration":"achref","imageRes":"http://127.0.0.1/asd.jpg"}]}
>   W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value
>   {"result":[{"id":"1","duration":"achref","imageRes":"http://127.0.0.1/asd.jpg","mat":"achref","name":"achref"},{"id":"2","duration":"achref","imageRes":"http://127.0.0.1/asd.jpg","mat":"achref","name":"achref"},{"id":"3","duration":"achref","imageRes":"http://127.0.0.1/asd.jpg","mat":"achref","name":"achref"},{"id":"4","duration":"achref","imageRes":"http://127.0.0.1/asd.jpg","mat":"achref","name":"achref"},{"id":"5","duration":"achref","imageRes":"http://127.0.0.1/asd.jpg","mat":"achref","name":"achref"}]}
>   of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
>   W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
>   W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:96)
>   W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:108)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.example.wiola.prisonapp.fragments.PrisonnerListFragment.getPrisonersFromJson(PrisonnerListFragment.java:166)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.example.wiola.prisonapp.fragments.PrisonnerListFragment$AsyncGetPrisoners.doInBackground(PrisonnerListFragment.java:103)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.example.wiola.prisonapp.fragments.PrisonnerListFragment$AsyncGetPrisoners.doInBackground(PrisonnerListFragment.java:87)
>   W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) W/System.err:
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

```
and php file

>  <?php define('HOST','localhost'); define('USER','root');
> define('PASS',''); define('DB','achrefDB');   $con =
> mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);   $sql = "select * from Prisonner";
> $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);   $result = array();   while($row =
> mysqli_fetch_array($res)){ array_push($result, array('id'=>$row[0],
> 'name'=>$row[1], 'mat'=>$row[2], 'duration'=>$row[3],
> 'imageRes'=>$row[4]   
> 
> )); }   echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));  
> mysqli_close($con);   ?>
```

could help me?
thank you :)

this java file

```
public class PrisonnerListFragment extends Fragment {

    ListView lvprisonners;
    private PrisonnerAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Prisonner> prisoners;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public PrisonnerListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_prisonner_list, container, false);
        lvprisonners = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_prisonners);

        new AsyncGetPrisoners().execute();


        return view;
    }

    class AsyncGetPrisoners extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            prisoners = new ArrayList<>();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            dialog.setTitle("In Progress");
            dialog.setMessage("En cours du traitement");
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String jsonStream = request("http://192.168.0.100/connexion.php").toString();
            getPrisonersFromJson(prisoners, jsonStream);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);


            PrisonnerAdapter adapter = new PrisonnerAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_prisonner, prisoners);

            lvprisonners.setAdapter(adapter);

            lvprisonners.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    getFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.container,
                                    PrisonnerDetailFragment.newInstance(prisoners.get(position)))
                            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
                }
            });


            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

    public StringBuffer request(String urlString) {

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer("");
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("root", "");
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("REQUEST Result", "IOException = " + e.getMessage());
        }
        Log.d("REQUEST Result", "result = " + result);
        return result;

    }

    public void getPrisonersFromJson(List<Prisonner> prisoners,String json) {

        try {
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);

                Prisonner p;
                p = new Prisonner();

                p.setId(jsonObject.optInt("id"));
                p.setName(jsonObject.optString("name"));
                p.setMat(jsonObject.optString("mat"));
                p.setDuration(jsonObject.optString("duration"));
                p.setImageRes(jsonObject.optInt("imageRes"));


                prisoners.add(p);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

and this json

```
{"result":[{"id":"1","name":"achref","mat":"achref","duration":"achref","imageRes":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1\/asd.jpg"},{"id":"2","name":"achref","mat":"achref","duration":"achref","imageRes":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1\/asd.jpg"},{"id":"3","name":"achref","mat":"achref","duration":"achref","imageRes":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1\/asd.jpg"},{"id":"4","name":"achref","mat":"achref","duration":"achref","imageRes":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1\/asd.jpg"},{"id":"5","name":"achref","mat":"achref","duration":"achref","imageRes":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1\/asd.jpg"}]}
```

prisonnerAdapter

```
public class PrisonnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Prisonner> {

    Context context;
    int resource;
    public PrisonnerAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Prisonner> prisonners) {
        super(context, resource, prisonners);
        this.context=context;
        this.resource=resource;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        PrisonnerHolder holder = new PrisonnerHolder();

        if (view==null){

        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view =inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);



            holder.TvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_prisonner_name);
            holder.TvMat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_prisonner_mat);
            holder.TvDuration = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_prisonner_duration);
            //holder.ImgPrisonner = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_prisonner);
            Picasso.with(context).load(getItem(position).getImageRes()).into(holder.ImgPrisonner);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
          holder = (PrisonnerHolder) view.getTag();
        }


        holder.TvName.setText(getItem(position).getName());
        holder.TvMat.setText(getItem(position).getMat());
        holder.TvDuration.setText(getItem(position).getDuration());
        holder.ImgPrisonner.setBackgroundResource(getItem(position).getImageRes());

        return view;
    }

    class PrisonnerHolder {
        TextView TvName;
        TextView TvMat;
        TextView TvDuration;
        ImageView ImgPrisonner;

    }
}
```

Comment: you're receiving a JSON object and it looks like you're treating it as a JSON array, that's the error. We could help you further if you provided the client code

Comment: @nandsito thank you i added java file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the object use

```
 JSONArray resultArray = result.getJSONArray("result");
 for(int i = 0; i < resultArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = resultArray.getJSONObject(i);
                //store your variable
                String name = obj.getString("name");
 }
```

For more details
See in https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: ok now its working only picture didnt apear? maybe in json file its look like this : "http:\/\/127.0.0.1\/asd.jpg"

Answer (score 1):

Modify the beginning of this method:

```java
public void getPrisonersFromJson(List<Prisonner> prisoners, String json) {

    try {

        JSONObject result = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray array = result.getJSONArray("result");

        // ...
```

**UPDATE**

Like @Arcao mentioned, `imageRes` is a string URL but `Prisonner` class seems to store it as an `int`. Try to change it to `String` and it may work.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource ID must not be zero.
                      at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.load(Picasso.java:331)
                      at com.example.wiola.prisonapp.adapters.PrisonnerAdapter.getView(PrisonnerAdapter.java:54) i will add prisonner Adapter file

Comment: `p.setImageRes(jsonObject.optInt("imageRes"));` Why you convert here String url to int?

Comment: i follow tutorial and imageRes is int in prisonner  model

Comment: i changed  it to string and its work only the pics its cant load

Comment: @achref05 i couldn't understand what is the problem now. Is `imageRes` properly stored? Don't the pictures load?

Comment: @nandsito the pictures are stored in database when i run my app i have the all data only the picture maybe it problem the url of pic in json "http:\/\/127.0.0.1\/asd.jpg"

Comment: @achref05 it's an entire new question. I think it would be better if you opened another question. And you are sure that the other answer solved your problem better than mine?

Comment: @nandsito thank you very much i will ask in new quetion is better